# What is the longest lasting hyperinflationary period in history?

Tags: economy

I guess hyperinflation periods depend on the definition of hyperinflation, which makes it hard to define and find comparative data. I could find which has been the worse in terms of percentages (Hungary), but what has been historically the longest lasting one in terms of time duration? Is this information compared somewhere?

Much of what I find on the web is just "top worst cases of hyperinflationary periods" or "the 5 worst hyperinflations in history". These article are focused on percentages and not on time so I do not get a full list to check. Same with Wikipedia [hyperinflation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperinflation).

The books I have in hand are outdated and may not reflect anything after 2000.

According to this think tank CATO study (data up to 2008), it might be Nicaraguan hyperinflation, lasting 52 months
https://www.cato.org/sites/cato.org/files/pubs/pdf/hanke-krus-hyperinflation-table-may-2013.pdf . Are there better academic sources?

Comment: Good question, but I doubt it will be a long time. Eventually any currency will find its value. If its true value is zero, it will be replaced by a new currency.

Comment: @NeMo, if the behavior of currencies during hyperinflationary episodes is any indication, the approach to zero is invariably asymptotic.  This means there's no fundamental limit to how long hyperinflation can continue.